# Store Javascript Object to MySQL by using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-maps-api-3

How do I save Javascript Object to MySQL by using PHP ?
Right now Im using a google map API and It returns me a response Object

```
directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
    travelMode: 'BICYCLING'
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); //The Return Response
        //This function call ajax below to send response Obj with a key to store to MySQL
        storeRouteDB(storeLocations, response);
        showSteps(response, markerArray, display, map);
    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
});
```

And I use Ajax to send the Objet to my backend php

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/storedRouteDB.php',
    async: false,
    data: {key: key, value: value},
    error: function(){
        console.log("Error in Ajax");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        result = data;
    }
});
```

And in my php I do:

```
$key = $_REQUEST['key'];
$value = $_REQUEST['value'];
echo checkDB($key, $value);
function checkDB($key, $value) {
    $dbServerName = "localhost";
    $dbUserName="root";
    $dbPassword="";
    $dbName="myDB";
    ....
    // Trying to zip the object to String and save it as char to MYSQL
    $value_zip = serialize($value);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO storedRoute (locations, objects) VALUES ('$key', '$value_zip')";
```

But It I got result:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
at _.n.intersects (js?key=AIzaSyAbBYjTy8g4-dGYAl4_mHmWDVoWGEziq6c&callback=initMap:147)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
```

How to fix this bug? Or is there other Better way to store Javascript Object to MySQL by using PHP? thank you!

Comment: Applications using the Directions API are bound by the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service. [Section 3.2.4(a)](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license) of the terms states that you must not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content except under the limited conditions stated in the terms.

Answer (score -1):

I usually do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/storedRouteDB.php',
    async: false,
    data: 'data='+JSON.stringify({key: key, value: value}),
    error: function(){
        console.log("Error in Ajax");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        result = data;
    }
});
```

Then you can access the object in `$_POST['data']`. Maybe you want to decode it too with `json_decode`. Let me know if it did work.

Comment: "Then you can access the object in $_REQUEST['data']" `$_REQUEST['data']` it's bad because `$_REQUEST` is set with data from GET, POST, COOKIE data. Use `$_GET['data']` instead off `$_REQUEST['data']`.. the `$_REQUEST` array is more or less like a "global" which i tend to avoid at any costs.

Comment: Well, I will update my answer then and maybe remove the `GET` type and replace it with `POST` too. Thanks

Comment: Also, that will not be portable across versions of the API.